# Deleted users still apear in terminal output

Tags: linux, ubuntu, login, users, terminal

ubuntu 16.04 lts

After creating a user with useradd

```
sudo useradd -G sudo -m -d /home/user -s /bin/bash user
```

and then deleting it with

```
`sudo deluser user`
```

the user still appears after typing

```
 ls -l /home
```

Shouldn't it be gone?

output of `ls -l /home`

```
ls -l /home
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 1000 1000 4096 Jun  6 15:04 user
```

p.s. it also prompts for a user password even though a user password has not been set when trying to log in to the user. After creating the user the server cannot be accessed with the user. Only when using `ecryptfs-utils` can a password for the user be set.

Answer (score 2):

Per the man page.  [deluser](http://man.he.net/man8/deluser) does not remove the home directories unless you pass the `--remove-home` option.

Man

> By default, deluser will remove the user **without removing** the home directory, the mail spool or any other files on the system owned by the user. Removing the home directory and mail spool can be achieved using the --remove-home option.

Also, if you want to know if a user is gone, a better command to run would be `getent passwd` or `getent passwd username`